# How to calculate average of a column and then include in a select query Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a query where the result like the following

| Date | Reach |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-12 | 461 |
| 2021-01-14 | 1770 |
| 2021-01-20 | 397 |
| 2021-01-26 | 117 |
| 2021-01-28 | 275 |
| 2021-01-28 | 267 |

I want the Average of Amount like this

| Date | Reach | avg reach |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-12 | 461 | 523.8 |
| 2021-01-14 | 1770 | 523.8 |
| 2021-01-20 | 397 | 523.8 |
| 2021-01-26 | 117 | 523.8 |
| 2021-01-28 | 275 | 523.8 |
| 2021-01-28 | 267 | 523.8 |

I know to calculate the avg value but i want it included with the result of query.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. im new to using query's in Google sheets

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is not answerable as is.  Please either show us your statement that gives you your current values; or show us sample data and column names so that we can provide some assistance.. Any answer to this question as written would be pure guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the data is in `E2:F7`

#### Formula:

`=query(query(E2:F7, "select E, F, "&average(F2:F7)), "offset 1", 0)`

I just appended the value of average of the reach column to the query itself.

#### Output:

[image: Output]